Unique coupling
Let $X$ be a Polish metric space, and let $\mu,\nu$ be two Borel probability measures on $X$, when is the product measure the only coupling of $\mu$ and $\nu$. More formally, let $$\Gamma(\mu,\nu):=\{\pi\textrm{ Borel probability measure on }X\times X: \pi_1=\mu, \pi_2=\nu\}$$
Where $\pi_1,\pi_2$ are the marginal distributions of $\pi$ on the two factors. Are there known results providins sufficient conditions for $\Gamma$ to be a singleton.
PS pf course one trivial case where this happens is when $X$ is a singleton or when both measures are Diracs.

I assume that you refer to coupling of measures; and not “couponing” as you wrote. I have edited the question accordingly.

The only way this can happen is the situation that you described, where at least one of the measures gives full measure to a single point. In fact, the proof below does not require the two Polish spaces to be the same.
If not, let $0<\mu(A)<1$ and $0<\nu(B)<1$. We may assume, without loss of generality, that $\mu(A)\le \frac 12\le\nu(B)$: if this is not the case, replace $A$ and $B$ or both by their complements. Then define a coupling $\lambda$ by
$$\lambda(S)=
\frac{\mu\times\nu(S\cap(A\times B))}{\nu(B)}+\frac{\mu\times\nu(S\cap(A^c\times B^c))}{\mu(A^c)}
+\frac{\nu(B)-\mu(A)}{\mu(A^c)\nu(B)}\mu\times\nu(S\cap(A^c\times B)).
$$
To verify this, we first observe that $\nu(B)-\mu(A)=\mu(A^c)-\nu(B^c)$. Then we see that for any set $C$,
$$
\lambda(C\times X)=\frac{\mu(C\cap A)\nu(B)}{\nu(B)}+\frac{\mu(C\cap A^c)\nu(B^c)}{\mu(A^c)}+\frac{\nu(B)-\mu(A)}{\mu(A^c)\nu(B)}\mu(C\cap A^c)\nu(B)
$$
$$
=\mu(C\cap A)+\mu(C\cap A^c)\left(\frac{\nu(B^c)}{\mu(A^c)}
+\frac{\mu(A^c)-\nu(B^c)}{\mu(A^c)}\right).
$$
This sums to $\mu(C)$. A similar calculation shows $\lambda(X\times D)=\nu(D)$.

For two measurable sets $A,B$, let $p=\mu(A)$ and $q=\nu(B)$. Consider any coupling of a Bernoulli$(p)$ and a Bernoulli$(q)$, say, $C:\{0,1\}^2 \to [0,1]$. Then we can  find a coupling $(X,Y)$ of $\mu$ and $\nu$ with
\begin{align}
(X\in A, Y\in B) = q(1,1),\qquad
(X\in A, Y\in B^c)= q(1,0),
\\(X\in A^c, Y\in B^)= q(0,1),\qquad
(X\in A^c, Y\in B^c)= q(0,0).
\end{align}
For convenience, denote $A^1=A$ and $A^0=A^c$, similarly $B^1=B$ and $B^0=B^c$.
Sample an iid sequence with the product measure $\mu\times \nu$, say $(X_t,Y_t)_{t\ge 1}$.
Sample $(U,V)\sim q$, return $(X_T,Y_T)$ where $T=\min\{t\ge 1: X_t\in A^U, Y_t\in B^V\}$. This is a way to construct conditional distributions given that a an independent pair belong to one of $(A,B)$, $(A^c,B)$, $(A, B^c)$, $(A^c,B^c)$.
The conditional distribution is given by $P(X_T\in D|U=u, V=v)=\mu(D\cap A^u)/\mu(A^u)$. The law of $X_T$ is the desired marginal:
$$
P(X_T\in D)=\sum_{u=0}^1\sum_{v=0}^1
P(X_T\in D|U=u, V=v)
q(u,v)=\sum_{u=0}^1\sum_{v=0}^1
\frac{\mu(D\cap A^u)}{\mu(A^u)}
q(u,v)
$$
which is $\mu(D)$ as the denominator cancels with $\sum_v q(u,v)$.
Furthermore the pushforward $(\mathbf 1\{X_T\in A\}, \mathbf 1\{Y_T\in B\})$ is distributed according to $q$ by construction.
As as long as we can find two sets $A,B$ with $\mu(A)\in (0,1)$ and $\nu(B)\in(0,1)$, we can construct infinitely many distinct couplings of $\mu$ and $\nu$ corresponding to distinct couplings of Bernoulli$(\mu(A))$ and Bernoulli$(\mu(B))$. One of these couplings is the same as that in the accepted answer, so the above construction is likely just different words for the same argument.

This is nice, and probably explains more clearly why you get the right marginals.
